# Error logic of array loop gives a double (unexpected) result when the program is run

Tags: c, arrays, loops

so I've been working on my code. I have these struct

```
typedef char infotype;
typedef int letak;

typedef struct {
  infotype info;
  letak parent, firstson, nextsibling;
} node;

typedef node tree;
```

and  i mean to make the "tree" into an array of node and assign it, so i make these procedure :

```
void createTree(tree T[])
{
  T[0].parent = 0;
  T[0].nextsibling = 0;
}

void createNode(tree T[], int k, int i, char value)
{
  if(i == 0)
  {
    T[i].info = value;
    T[i].firstson = i+1;
  }
  else
  {
    T[i].info = value;
    T[i].parent = (i-1) / k;
    T[i].firstson = (i * k) + 1;

    if (i % k == 0)
     {
        printf("Sorry but you cannot have any sibling!");
     }

    else
    {
        T[i].nextsibling = i+1;
    }
   }
  }
```

and my main driver is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int maksimum;
  tree pohon[maksimum];
  int i = 0;
  char info;

  maksimum = 3;

  createTree(pohon);

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) //here things get weird
  {
    printf("Input the node name : ");
    scanf("%c", &info);
    createNode(pohon, 4, i, info);
  }

  return 0;
 }
```

while i run my program it gaves me :

Input the node name : a

Input the node name : Input the node name : b

('a' is the input from the user as well), but i expected it to be :

Input the node name : a

Input the node name : b

Input the node name : c

can anyone tell me where did I get it wrong?

Comment: After you scan the first node name, a newline (at least) remains unread in the input.  `scanf` would skip that and / or any other whitespace before scanning most input directives, but it does not skip whitespace before processing `%c` directives (thus allowing whitespace characters themselves to be scanned).  That newline is scanned by your second `scanf` call.  There are numerous previous questions around here that revolve around the same issue.

Comment: I tried to put a white space like " %c" and it works. Thank you so much for helping!!

Comment: This declaration won't work:  `tree pohon[maksimum];` ssince `maksimum` is undefined at that point.  It needs to be defined when the declaration is reached, not after.  So you're getting some serious undefined behavior there.  Don't waste time on anything else until you fix that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The most pressing problem is the unknown size of `pohon`.  Nothing else is predictable until that's fixed.  OP should enable warnings when compiling.

Comment: thank you for the warning, i already change the maksimum into certain value